# How to validate token from another API in my spring boot API application?

Tags: spring-boot, api, security

I have implemented APIs in my Spring boot application. I want to secure the API calls. The flow should be my API is called with Auth token in header -> my API app validate the token by calling another API -> if validation is successful than response is sent else unauthorized msg sent. How do i do this? I am new with this security implementation.
Thanks!